# Как сделать авторазметку grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

При заполнении колонки кнопками до низа, появляется прокрутка вниз. Как вместо прокрутки сделать добавление второго столбца и продолжить выводить во второй столбец?

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="auto">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" " Name="GridCol">
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `WrapPanel` с вертикальной ориентацией:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
</WrapPanel>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]